# import ansible.module_utils in 2.2.1.0 as part of inventory module

Tags: python, import, ansible, ansible-inventory

Importing UTILS classes into Inventory - can it be done?

I have created a custom LDAP data importer as part of creating my inventory class. The LDAP schema we have wasn't similar enough to the LDAP plugin provided in samples.

My class is called ldapDataModule; the class is in:

```
/home/agt/ansible/agt_module_utils/ldapDataModule.py
```

My "$HOME/.ansible.cfg" file has the following:

```
module_utils = /home/agt/ansible/agt_module_utils
```

When running my Ansible inventory module, I get the following output:

> ansible ecomtest37 -m ping
>   ERROR! Attempted to execute "/sites/utils/local/ansible/hosts" as 
>   inventory script: Inventory script (/sites/utils/local/ansible/hosts) had
>   an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/sites/utils/local/ansible/hosts", line 22, in 
>      from ansible.module_utils import ldapDataModule
>   ImportError: No module named module.utils

The include statement inside hosts appears like this:

```
import copy
import ldap
import re
import sys
import operator
import os
import argparse
import datetime
import os.path
try:
    import json
except:
    import simplejson as json
from ansible.module_utils import ldapDataModule

class agtInventory(object):
```

RECOMENDATIONS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do the following as a "work around". I'd still like to hear from Ansible guru's on proper use of "module_utils" variable from ansible.cfg

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/agt/ansible/agt_module_utils')

from ldapDataModule import ldapDataModule
```

Comment: AFAIK, path overriding magic works only for modules/plugins. But inventory scripts are from another world. You should wait for Ansible 2.4 release, where inventory is revamped completely with support of inventory plugins – this should work as any other plugins.

Comment: Good to know. Don't change too much please :D the current inventory mechanism (aka API) - although slow - is 'fine'. Ideally, I'd like to see a more complete API to implement in my inventory module (instead of only 2 methods) because doing a "host var search" for every single host in large groups is expensive but at least it was simple enough to implement.  -Thanks again for the help